# Convert json to pandas with no header

Tags: python, pandas

I have an incoming json from a http request. I can get the result back without problems. But i can't seem to get it into a dataframe. I will end up as null when doing this. I have tried with several variations of dataframe and other. But it will either end up null och with throwing an error.

```
r=requests.get(URL + '/%s' % cmd ,auth = auth, headers=headers)
jsonRes = r.json()
res = json.dumps(jsonRes, indent=4)
print(res)
df = pd.read_json(res)
df.head()
```

The incoming data looks like this.

```
[
    {
        "delayed": 900,
        "src": "CME",
        "identifier": "ENQ100-1",
        "type": "INDEX",
        "country": "US",
        "open": "14:30:00",
        "close": "21:00:00",
        "name": "NQ 100 Fut."
    }
]
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(json.loads(r))` works for me on after using `json.dumps`

Comment: When writing `res = json.dumps(jsonRes, indent=4)` you revert your JSON object back to a string. What you want however, is to create a DataFrame from your JSON. Try to use the actual JSON object `jsonRes` to create a DataFrame like `pd.DataFrame.from_records(jsonRes)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the second comment it was crystal clear. Just posting the answer for clarity.

Using the incoming JSON directly with the from_records will correctly create the dataframe. Also for me coming from Spark I tried with different things like head() etc. for printing the dataframe. This can be done directly by printing the df.

Note that I have not tried this with a nested dataframe.

```
def req(auth, headers, cmd=''):
    r=requests.get(URL + '/%s' % cmd ,auth = auth, headers=headers)
    jsonRes = r.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(jsonRes) # Use the Json directly
    print(df)
```